# Что значат символы % b $ в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Недавно начал изучать вордпресс. Интересует, что значит подобное использование символов $ и %, например, при создании нескольких панелей виджетов:

```
'name'          => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
'id'            => "sidebar-$i",
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
```

Собственно, интересно узнать про то, как это использовать и где про это можно почитать.

Comment: @Sizel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В данной ситуации код, который вы написали, запускается в цикле.

При каждой итерации переменная $i возрастает на 1, за счет чего регистрируются $i штук виджетов с названиями Sidebar 1, Sidebar 2, Sidebar 3 и т.д.
Каждый из этих виджетов имеет свой уникальный ID sidebar-1, sidebar-2, sidebar-3 и т.д.

И каждый < li > имеет свой класс и ид.

Comment: А где в данном случае переменная i задается?

Comment: перед этими строчками должен идти код for ($i=1; $i<3 $i++)